# Is [O2] different in a 5 mL liquid media?

Tags: bacteriology

Is there a drastic difference between top and bottom of the tube, with no stirring?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe there is. As you can see in the image below, strictly anaerobic bacteria can survive in liquid medium in test tubes, herefore they will migrate to the bodem of the medium to avoid Oxygen. Also you can see that microaerophiles, which require an oxygen percentage of approximately 2-10% (versus approximately 20% in normal air), will be able to survive below the surface of the medium.

So yes, there is a drastic change, seeing as obligate aerobic bacteria can surive at the surface of the medium, and obligate anaerobic bacteria can survive at the bodem.

[image]

To this I have one caveat to add. Namely that these tests are normally done in standard test tubes (approximately 9, 22 or 28mL depending on size), which would most likely contain more medium. So I am not absolutely sure, nor have I found any specific information on oxygen gradients in 5mL tubes. You could test this by performing the experiment in described in the figure in your tubes with 5mL medium and see what happens. Then you will definitely know.

Hope this helps!